# Javascript function to Php

Tags: php, javascript, decode, encode

I need to encode a password to hexadecimal in javscript and then decode it in php. I have a function that does the two things but in javascript. I tried to transform it to php but there are some javascript native functions that i dont know what is the php equivalent.

**The function to encode (Javascript)**

```
function encodeToHex(str){
    var r="";
    var e=str.length;
    var c=0;
    var h;
    while(c<e){
        h=str.charCodeAt(c++).toString(16);
        while(h.length<3) h="0"+h;
        r+=h;
    }
    return r;
}
```

**The function to decode (Javascript)**

```
function decodeFromHex(str){
    var r="";
    var e=str.length;
    var s;
    while(e>=0){
        s=e-3;
        r=String.fromCharCode("0x"+str.substring(s,e))+r;
        e=s;
    }
    return r;
}
```

**The function to decode (PHP)** << This is what im trying to achieve

```
function decodeFromHex($str){
$r="";
$e=str.length;
$s;
while($e>=0){
        $s=$e-3;
        $r=String.fromCharCode("0x"+str.substring($s,$e))+$r;
        $e=$s;
    }
    return $r;
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php ?

Comment: In javascript, you can use `parseInt('255', 16); // 0xFF` to encode and `parseInt('0xFF', 10); // 255` to decode... And if it is already an integer, `number.toString(16)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need [hexdec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php) and [dechex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php) functions.

By the way, you get string length in php via `strlen()`.

On a last note, client side encoding is quite pointless, as it's easy to sniff and decode your data - use SSL over HTTPS if you want to be sure.

Comment: I dont know very much about encoding and security. The most common thing that i do is use md5 but in this case i need to decode it so that dosnt work for me. How i use SSL. Do you have some link to recommend me?

Answer (score 0):

Decoding HEX values in PHP can be done using either:

```
current(unpack('H*', $str))
```

Or:

```
hex2bin($str);
```

*I'm hoping that you're not really encoding passwords into HEX though*

Comment: Yes. I was going to use md5 but i need to decode the password too and in md5 i cant do that. Also i need that the encoding that i do works in javacsript and also in php. What do you recomend me?

Comment: @JonathanCalb in that case you may as well send it in clear text; encoding in hexadecimal ain't going to give any more protection unless you set up your server to use SSL (there are many howtos on that)